# Mysql library cannot be found

Tags: mysql, c, compilation, include, centos7

I have mysql-devel installed. Relevant libraries live under `/usr/inlcude/mysql`

Here's my sample code to be compiled on Centos7:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

Error message:

```
Mysql_test.c:1:23: fatal error: my_global.h: No such file or directory
#include <my_global.h>
```

What is the problem? Should I create echos of all libraries under `/usr/include/mysql` to the primary path `/usr/include`?

Comment: Need to fix your code snippet, can't tell what you're including

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add mysql include to your compilation, as you suspected:

```
-I/usr/include/mysql
```

Then just

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <my_global.h>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Here's what I found with the location flag: **/tmp/ccSOjzqU.o: In function 'main':
Mysql_test.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**  Seems like the header file is not properly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you using gcc include like this :

```
#include <mysql/my_global.h>
```

If you use gcc dont need to specify `-I`

Depend where is mysql include dir . And where is located `my_global.h`

---

EDIT :

```
g++ -g -Wall -I/usr/local/include test2.o Test.o -o test
```

Soo add to you compiler this : `-I/usr/local/include` and include like this `#include <mysql/my_global.h>`

---

TO solve undefined reference you need to like to the library path . `mysqlclient.a/.so`
And add this too to link the library

```
g++ -g -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/path_to_lib -lmysqlclient test2.o Test.o -o test
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. However I'm getting another error as follows:      **/usr/include/mysql/my_global.h:68:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
#include <my_config.h>**  and at this time, specifying location of the config header file won't work...

Comment: EDITED, try like this